# Help understanding proof that unitary matrices are length preserving

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, unitary-matrices

I'm working through the article [Quantum Computing for the Very Curious](https://quantum.country/qcvc#part-II) and am stuck on one aspect of the proof it gives for unitary matrices being length preserving. I've included an annotated screenshot as I can't link to this specific part of the article: [image: screenshot of proof]

My question is: at the place I've marked with the red arrow, why did the author introduce the index k?

The sum is over the product of the jth entry of $U\psi$ and $(U\psi)^*$ i.e. the same entry in both vectors. If $(U\psi)_j$ expands to $\sum_{l}U_{jl}\psi_l$ (as explained above), then couldn't we write $(U\psi)^*_j$ as $\sum_{l}U^*_{jl}\psi^*_l$ and eliminate the need for the k index?

I get that it ultimately works because lower down $\delta_{kl}$ is zero whenever k != l. But it seems like the proof would be simpler without introducing k:

$$\|U|\psi \rangle \|^2 = \sum_j(U\psi)^*_j(U\psi)_j$$

$$= \sum_{jl}U^*_{jl}\psi^*_lU_{jl}\psi_l$$

$$= \sum_{jl}U^*_{jl}U_{jl}\psi^*_l\psi_l$$

$$= \sum_{jl}U^\dagger_{lj}U_{jl}\psi^*_l\psi_l$$

$$= \sum_{l}I_{ll}\psi^*_l\psi_l$$

$$= \sum_{l}\psi^*_l\psi_l$$

$$= \|\psi\|^2$$

Overall, the proof in the article (and others like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2850254/748472) make sense to me but I was surprised / thrown off by the k above and since this is all new to me, I can't shake the feeling that I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance for indulging me.

Comment: The thing is that you expand two different terms, so you need two different indices. For instance, when expanding $(a+b)(c+d+e)$, the final sum has $6=2 \times 3$ terms. In general, if you’re expanding $AB$, where $A$ and $B$ are sums of $n$ terms, there will be $n^2$ terms in the expansion, requiring two indices. It’s merely a coincidence in this case that terms with $k \neq l$ ultimately contribute nothing.

Comment: Thank you, @Mindlack for your explanation. It took me a while to grok what you're saying and when I did, it revealed a deeper misunderstanding on my part, so I'm glad I pushed on this (I had wondered if I was just splitting hairs when I wrote the post). I think what confused me was this: I saw we're multiplying the jth element of  $U\psi$ and $(U\psi)^*$ i.e. the same element index in both vectors, but didn't see that each of those terms is itself a sum of many terms and we have to multiply their sums together, resulting in the $n^2$ expansion, as you say.

Comment: I think having all the sums squished into the single $\sum$ rather than seeing the intermediate step of $\sum_j(\sum_{k}U^*_{jk}\psi^*_k)(\sum_jU_{jl}\psi_l)$ confused me. Thanks again for taking the time to answer.